# What are the directories that systemd scans for a new service file that runs an application that does not belong to the OS?

Tags: linux, services, systemd

I need to create a new systemd service that launches an application stored in `/opt/myApp/`, where should I create a `myService.service` file on the Linux filesystem ?

EDIT0 : I created my service into `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/` and it works fine, systemd can "see" it :

```bash
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep filmanagerv1-backup.service
filmanagerv1-backup.service                                                disabled        enabled
$ sudo systemctl enable filmanagerv1-backup.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/filmanagerv1-backup.service → /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/filmanagerv1-backup.service.
$
```

Comment: `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224992/where-do-i-put-my-systemd-unit-file`

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks :+1: